# IdentityServer4 missing properties known in version 3

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

I'm trying to setup IdentityServer 4 (1.0.0-rc2) server. I've followed the instruction in the documentation (http://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/) but it seems to lack some features that I was familiar with from IdentityServer3.

I found this article (http://elemarjr.com/en/2016/04/18/learning-identityserver4-part-1-securing-an-webapi/) about IdentityServer4, but some of the things that were demonstrated in the article don't seem to be avilable in the latest version (I guess that article was written against an older version).

I found that in order to setup a certificate, instead of setting it up in the IdentityServerOptions object I need to set it directly on the builder object. So instead of doing this:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.SigningCertificate = certificate;
});
```

I now do this:

```
builder.SetSigningCredential(certificate);
```

1. What I can't seem to find is how to define `RequireSsl` property.
2. How do I set `IdentityServerFactory` setting?

Is there a place that contains more documentation on IdentityServer4?

Comment: http://docs.identityserver.io

Comment: @leastprivilege read the first sentence in my question please. documentation doesn't have that information and is far from documenting the full features - it's more a step by step instructions with no followup.

Comment: Well. That's all we have right now. In that case - check the source code ;)

Comment: @leastprivilege - already did - from what I see, the source code contains more options than exists when downloading from NuGet - I'm trying to compile from source and reference and see how it goes. Why does NuGet doesn't contain all that's in source?

Comment: @leastprivilege I now see that `RequireSsl` had been commented out in source code - any reason for not including it anymore? thanks

Comment: @leastprivilege event reading this https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4 there seem to be missing stuff in the package that's on NuGet like `AddOperationalStore`

Comment: `AddOperationalStore` is part of `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework`, which is a separate nuget package

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer4 is built on top of MVC Core, so you can require https using MVC:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
                        options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()));
        }
```